# UWP vs WPF: System.Globalization CultureInfo is different?

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces, uwp, globalization

**Setup:**

- VS2015 C# solution
- Contains one UWP project
- Contains one WPF project
- Both projects declare `var ci = new CultureInfo(1)`

**Question(s):**

- *Why does the WPF project **find** the constructor taking an int, but the UWP project **does not**?*
- Why does browsing the System.Globalization namespace on msdn state that it should be there, if it's not there for UWP?
- How can we browse the MSDN APIs that are relevant to a particular target type/profile?

Comment: LCID was deprecated 10 years ago.  Microsoft does eventually make good on their promise, WinRT was the obvious vehicle.  Backgrounder [is here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2013/10/23/lcids-vs-locale-names-and-the-deprecation-of-lcids/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, basically some members are available on some platforms but not others. Look at the version information for [`CultureInfo(int)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/205h6kwc(v=vs.110).aspx) vs [`CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat(v=vs.110).aspx) in the Version Information section, as an example.

Constructor Version Information:

> **.NET Framework**
>   Available since 1.1

DateTimeFormat Version Information:

> **Universal Windows Platform**
>   Available since 4.5
>   **.NET Framework**
>   Available since 1.1
>   **Portable Class Library**
>   Supported in: portable .NET platforms
>   **Silverlight**
>   Available since 2.0
>   **Windows Phone Silverlight**
>   Available since 7.0
>   **Windows Phone**
>   Available since 8.1

Note the lack of mention of UWP on the constructor docs...

Comment: Ah, I see. So there currently isn't a way to filter msdn api documentation based on version/target information? Thx

Comment: @JSalazar: Not that I know of, I'm afraid. And it gets more complicated with all the DNX story...